# Some reserve words in R language are creating problem for Text Analytics

Tags: r, text, analysis, reserved-words

I have Document Term Matrix turned data frame with 352 observations of 1342 variables. Now when I try to run a randomforest model I get the error:

```
model <- randomForest(labels~ ., data = train_df, ntree = 100)
```

Error in model.frame.default(terms(reformulate(attributes(Terms)$term.labels)),  :
invalid type (special) for variable 'repeat'

I know 'repeat' is a reserve word in R, but how can I solve this issue. I cannot even change the column name in this condition and find it difficult to find a solution on net.

Help in this matter will be highly appreciated.

I have tried this but is doesnt help:

```
model <- randomForest(labels~ ., data = train_df, ntree = 100, `repeat` = train_df$`repeat`)
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the words to capitals with `toupper`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I can't replicate the issue. I get no error with `dd <- data.frame(`repeat`=rnorm(100), labels=runif(100)); randomForest(labels~., data=dd)`

Comment: Somewhere you appear to be converting your text labels into  the equivalent of `eval()` .   Either that or  you named a variable in your current environment the same as a function name, which is bad practice whether the name is "repeat" , "sin" , "c",  or any non-reserved function name.